# E(x)clipe on Juno

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml

I am trying to install JavaFX on Juno, but it fails.The site http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html is not helping me.
I want to  use FXML files designed on JavaFXSceneBuilder to JavaFX projects.I am running Java 1.8 JDK and Juno. I dont want to upgrade to Kepler.How to go about it?

I am following the steps from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8ObjkJXGIM

Thanks

javaz

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy your FXML file in your eclipse project package.
2. Add `jfxrt.jar` to your project library.

   The jar file should be available under `Oracle\JavaFX2.0\rt\lib`, if you have installed the JavaFX SDK separately.
3. Create a class that extends `Application`.
4. Under the `start()` method write ...

   ```
   Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Demo.fxml"));

   Scene scene = new Scene(root);
   stage.setScene(scene);

   stage.setTitle("FXML DEMO");
   stage.show();
   ```

`Demo.fxml` is the FXML file you designed using the [JavaFX SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html).

Comment: Thanks it works. I have jdk 1.8 installed so jfxrt.jar was already included i guess in the project JavaFX library.